# Controller filenames starting with P cause Routing problems

Tags: symfony, controller, routes, yaml

I recently created a controller called PublishBannerController.php It was a cut and paste of a previous Controller with all the various parts adjusted accordingly. The only problem is, I get this error when I try and load it:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Me\MyBundle\Controller?ublishBannerController' not found in /.../public_html/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php line 3190
```

I have replaced the square that appears, with a ? as the square really messes with stackOverflows editor.
It seems that the Symfony 2 parser converts paths containing \P into the special character that that represents.
As you can see below in appDevDebugProjectContainer.php anywhere where it is \P it converts it, even in the comments. Anywhere it contains _P etc. it is fine.

```
/*
* Gets the 'me.controller.publishbanner' service.
*
* This service is shared.
* This method always returns the same instance of the service.
*
* @return Me\MyBundle\Controller?ublishBannerController A Me\MyBundle\Controller?ublishBannerController instance.
*/
protected function getMe_Controller_PublishbannerService()
{
$this->services['me.controller.publishbanner'] = $instance = new \Me\MyBundle\Controller?ublishBannerController();

$instance->setContainer($this);

return $instance;
}
```

Here is my routing.yml

```
me_site_publishbanner:
    pattern:  /publishbanner
    defaults: { _controller: me.controller.publishbanner:indexAction }
```

And services.yml

```
me.controller.publishbanner:
    class:  "Me\MyBundle\Controller\PublishBannerController"
    shared: true
    calls:
        - [ setContainer, ["@service_container"] ]
```

Am I making a mistake somewhere or is this a bug in Symfony 2? Are you basically not allowed to create controller names starting with P?

Obviously, it is a Unicode issue and relates to this:
http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

And I have this set in my php.ini:

```
default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

I just wasn't expecting to come across this sort of issue in Symfony 2.

Comment: You probably accidentally introduced a control character in your service class string.  Drop the double quotes (not needed) and retype the controller class name.  And use single quotes around @service_container.  They are not really needed either but some IDEs complain about the @ symbol.  I doubt very much is it's a unicode thing.  I thin the \P is causing issues with double quotes.

Comment: @Cerad Want to add that as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: Sure.  Was it the double quotes or did you have a hidden character?

Comment: Such a weird error, so I was glad someone else came across this already.  Also, I found the stack trace pointed to comment lines, which was no help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use double quotes in your yaml file for string delimiters.  It would appear that, with double quotes, \ characters get converted in to their escaped values.

No real need to use any quotes at all for class names.

If you do want to quote things like @service to avoid warnings that some broken yaml processor issue then use single quotes.

Comment: Thanks. It was the double quotes in the YAML which did for me.